# Can't return newly created Parse Object with Parse Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Very strange issue- I can create a new object, but I can't return the newly created object.

I can return the object.id, object.get("name"), but just not the entire object. I'm using XCode 6.1.1 deploying on iPhone 4s 7.1.2.

Any thoughts?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCityChatRoom", function(request,response){
  var CityChat = Parse.Object.extend(constants.kBPCityChatRoomClassKey);
  var cityChat = new CityChat();

  cityChat.set(constants.kBPGroupChatRoomEndDate, request.params.endDate);
  cityChat.set(constants.kBPCityChatRoomCreatingUser, request.user);
  cityChat.set(constants.KBPCityChatRoomLocation, request.params.location);
  cityChat.set(constants.kBPCityChatRoomCityName, request.params.cityName);

  if(request.params.chatName){
    cityChat.set(constants.kBPCityChatRoomChatName, request.params.chatName)
  }
  else{
    var chatName = request.params.cityName+" tonight";
    cityChat.set(constants.kBPCityChatRoomChatName, chatName);
  }

  cityChat.save().then(function(results){
      console.log(results.id); // returns objectid
      console.log(results.get("name")); // returns name
      response.success(results);
  }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you run this with curl and paste the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax:

```
cityChat.save(null, {
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.id); // returns objectid
        console.log(result.get("name")); // returns name
        response.success(result);
        // or
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```